# angular ui modal after close event return data object

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

How can I get the event in the curtain outside the model so I can send data when closing the modal?

This is what I'm doing, but I'm still not getting results. Look almost in every post and I did not find anything like it.

This is the parent controller.

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
size: size,
resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.items;
    }
 }
});

 modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
$scope.selected = selectedItem;
 }, function (DateReceived) {
 console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
 console.log("Here I want to receive a parameter sent from the child controller.");
 console.log(DateReceived);
});
```

Here I want to receive a parameter sent from the child controller: ModalInstanceCtrl.

```
$modalInstance.result.finally({
    DataSend: $scope.items
});
```

Try to do it with this too and nothing.

```
 $scope.$on('modal.closing', function(event, reason, closed) {
    if (reason == "backdrop click" || reason == "escape key press") {
        event.preventDefault();
        $modalInstance.close({
            DataSend: $scope.items
        });
    }
});
```

And the $modalInstance.close({ DataSend: $scope.items }); is not working this shows me in the console [result in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROOLA.png)

I really do not know how to send and receive data when I close the model, which I think is wrong because I'm not getting results.

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Wiered `$modalInstance.close({
            DataSend: $scope.items
        });` should work anyway, can you add plunker with problem statement??

Comment: Connection timed out with plnker.co Can not be here.
And the $modalInstance.close({ DataSend: $scope.items }); is not working this shows me in the console. 
Edit it and put the image above

Comment: the first callback of your `modal.result.then` function will receive value which has been sent by `.close` method. here in this case you could put `console.log(selectedItem)` in 1st callback then you're all set..

Comment: That if it works for me, ie when I close the modal click on the close function, normal if it works. The problem is that I want it to send me when I click outside of the modal curtain, it is not in `modalInstance.result.then` if it is not `function (DateReceived) {console.log ('modal exit to:' + new Date ()); Console.log ("Here I want to receive a parameter sent from the child controller."); Console.log (DateReceived); });` That activates when I close the curtain.